# How do I make a parameter of a PowerShell function multi-valued?

Tags: powershell

I have the following that I would like to have the ability to use a single computer or do a get-content and do each for each item in the list just not sure how to accomplish this

```
function Search-Items {
  param ([string]$Server, [string]$SearchPath, [string]$SearchTerm)
  gci \\$Server\$SearchPath -r | ? {$_.Name -match $SearchTerm}
}
```

Tried the following but got nothing

```
function Search-Items {
  param ([string]$Servers, [string]$SearchPath, [string]$SearchTerm)
  ForEach ($server in $Servers) {
    gci \\$Server\$SearchPath -r | ? {$_.Name -match $SearchTerm}
  }
}
```

What I want to be able to do:

```
Search-Items -Servers $env:ComputerName
```

-or-

```
Search-Items -Servers gc .\list.txt
```

Changed `[string]$Servers` to `[array[]]$Servers`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I got it to work

```
function Search-Items {
  param ([array[]]$Servers, [string]$SearchPath, [string]$SearchTerm)
  ForEach ($server in $Servers) {
    gci \\$server\$SearchPath -r | ? {$_.Name -match $SearchTerm}
  }
}
```

Comment: You could also do this: `[string[]]$Servers`

Comment: @boeprox I figured that out last night but thanks for the tip :-)